# WKWebView : How to change Long press action or disable it?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, long-press

**Hi everyone** (why my greeting message is always deleted ??? !!! )

Even I read many topics about it, I didn't find a proper answer about my issue.

I would like to know if it's possible to disable a long press event on a wkwebview window or detect when the user use a long press event to do whatever I want?

Actually **I would like to copy an image link from a web site into a variable by using long press event** and I don't want the popup to be called at all.

I'm using **Swift**

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I did the same thing while ago in Swift, however it was UIWebView not WKWebView but assume it should be the same.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. How did you manage this on UIWebView ?

Comment: hey, so what I did was I added `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the `UIWebView` and also disable the `actionSheet` on that, then on LongPress my action was getting triggered and I was presenting a new view on top of the WebView on each LongPress.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I have two issue with this method : 

1 : how to disable the original long press action ?
2 : how to know the image file link where my finger is pressing on ?

Comment: Any update on that ?

Comment: Hi all, after all this time I still don't know how to do it... I have a function that work if I longtap on the screen, BUT only if the default menu is not trigerred. So I'm still wandering how to disable the default longpress menu action.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to disable the `pop up` view, while the highlighting is still there

```
func swizzle() {

    guard let cls = NSClassFromString("UICalloutBar") else { return }
    let originalSelector = NSSelectorFromString("appear")
    let swizzledSelector = #selector(UIView.appearHijack)
    let originMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, originalSelector)
    let swizzleMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIView.self, swizzledSelector)
    if let swizzledMethod = swizzleMethod, let originalMethod = originMethod{
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }
    
    
}
        



extension UIView{
    @objc func appearHijack(){
        
    }
}
```

`swizzle()` should be call once only.

---

How I know `UICalloutBar` ?

Just use `break point`, also `bt` is an option.

[image: 888]

Answer (score 1):

just `hijack` the relevant,

```
func swizzle(){
    guard let cls = NSClassFromString("UITextSelectionView") else { return }
    let originalSelector = NSSelectorFromString("updateSelectionRects")
    let swizzledSelector = #selector(UIView.updateSelectionRectsHijack)
    let originMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, originalSelector)
    let swizzleMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIView.self, swizzledSelector)
    if let swizzledMethod = swizzleMethod, let originalMethod = originMethod{
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }
}

extension UIView{
    @objc func updateSelectionRectsHijack(){ }
}
```

`swizzle()` should be call just once.

---

What is `UITextSelectionView` ?

Check `View Hierarchy`,

[image: 999]

---

What is method `updateSelectionRects`?

via `runtime`,

```
import ObjectiveC
    {
        var count: UInt32 = 0
        guard let methodArr = class_copyMethodList(NSClassFromString("UITextSelectionView"), &count) else { return }
        
        let cnt = Int(count)
        for i in 0..<cnt{
            let method = methodArr[i]
            let name = method_getName(method)
            if let type = method_getTypeEncoding(method){
                print(name, String(utf8String: type) ?? " _ | _ ")
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 16:

```
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
func swizzleiOS16() {
    guard let cls = NSClassFromString("UIEditMenuInteraction") else { return }
    let originalSelector = NSSelectorFromString("presentEditMenuWithConfiguration:")
    let swizzledSelector = #selector(UIEditMenuInteraction.presentEditMenuWithConfigurationHijack)
    let originMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, originalSelector)
    let swizzleMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIEditMenuInteraction.self, swizzledSelector)
    if let swizzledMethod = swizzleMethod, let originalMethod = originMethod{
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
extension UIEditMenuInteraction{
    @objc func presentEditMenuWithConfigurationHijack() {
}
```